# Re-scheduling local notifications on a daily basis

Tags: swift, scheduled-tasks, swift4, uilocalnotification

I'm working on an application notifying Muslims at prayer time. Every day, five different notifications need to be set, notifying the users it's time to pray.

I was able to schedule notifications for one day, but how can I set them every day again? The 5 times need to be changed every day without user interaction or having to open the app.

Is there some kind of callback when the last notification fires, so I can setup notifications for the next day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One way** is to schedule notifications for a week (5*7) if you can get their times correctly ,  on the basis of that the user may open your app at least once/week

**Other way** is to make use of background fetch capability where IOS wakes your app to run at any time On the assumption that you re-schedule them for a week from the launch time

Comment: Can you post a code of how to implement the second way?

Comment: Can I call a method when the last notification triggered to set notifications to next day?

Comment: you can't defer code to run at the last notification , structure your app to schedule notifications for an upcoming week every launch with the background fetch you will get it updated perfectly , also don't forget to give them a known identifier set to clear them before re-scheduling to have the latest values being set